# Pre-calculate Excel formulas when exporting data with python?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, xlslib

The code is pulling and then putting the excel formulas and not the calculated data of the formula.

```
xxtab.write(8, 3, "=H9+I9")
```

When this is read in and stored in that separate file, it is stored as "=H9+I9" and not the actual value of what H9 + I9 is. Then when we are importing it back it still is not calculating what H9 + I9 actually is, but instead it is just re-pasting "=H9+I9" into excel.

The intended goal is to have the math done either during export, after it is exported but before it is imported to another file, or during import.

The code should not be just placing another math function/formula into the next excel sheet. It should be putting an answer to whatever was being read.

```
import xlsxwriter, string, csv, time, datetime, subprocess, os
import urllib, urllib2, requests, openpyxl, sys
import gspread

# grab files
workbook = '/path/to/the/WorkBook.xlsx'

# Setup the spreadsheet
print "Creating workbook"
book = xlsxwriter.Workbook(workbook, {'strings_to_numbers': True})

# set matrix
row = 0  # row number
col = 0  # Column letter A=0 B=1 C=2 D=3...Z=26 ect.
# var.write(row, col, value, format)

# Make the sheet
xxtab = book.add_worksheet('DB Tables')

#Example of some .write commands which write to xxtab. The variables are taken directly from excel and are being read in by xlsl reader. This is stored in another file and is read in by the for loop.
xxtab.write(8, 1, "T_ACCESSRULES")
xxtab.write(8, 3, "=H9+I9")
xxtab.write(8, 7, "=data_dbmetrics!B56")

# The for loop, reads in a .txt file and does multiple .write commands
with open('/path/to/my/file/interns_xxtables.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for c, col in enumerate(reader):
        if(len(col) > 3):
            if (str(col[3]) == "bold"):
                xxtab.write(int(col[0]), int(col[1]), col[2], bold)
            elif (col[3] == "metric"):
                xxtab.write(int(col[0]), int(col[1]), col[2], metric)
            elif (col[3] == "title"):
                xxtab.write(int(col[0]), int(col[1]), col[2], title)
        else:
            xxtab.write(int(col[0]), int(col[1]), col[2])
f.close()
```

Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow. I am not sure how else to describe this question. I don't know how to get what I want, I just know what I want is not being achieved with what I have written.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense, and you haven't provided much (any?) actual code to go on. Please consider reviewing [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When I read data in from Excel I get the "cell value" which is whatever was typed into the cell, which happens to be the formulas. What I need to read is what the formula calculates. Therefor if the formula is adding two numbers, two cells, a range, or whatever, I need what the displayed answer is, not the formula. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: Again, it would be helpful if you showed your *actual code* or some reasonable approximation of it. How are you "reading in" the values? Do not answer me here in the comments, go back and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40248564/edit) your question to include these (useful) details.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Your edit was pretty massive, basically rewriting the whole question. Now it has code, which I guess is better, but that code doesn't seem like *actual* code that you've tried to use, or at least you've left out a lot of code (for example, where do `xxtab`, `bold`, `metric`, and `title` come from?).

Comment: Dang. I missed something when editing, dbtab was supposed to be "xxtab". My bad. Other than that the `bold/metric/title` are not really any concern with the question I am trying to get answered, so I never displayed where I declared what they are. Felt like "not useful to other readers" information. 

I have ran this code and the loop definitely reads in the data I have stored in the .txt file, it just doesn't run the calculations before entering it into excel, therefor it just places the formula in excel. Which I stated is the issue which I am having.

Comment: Personally, what I find more frustrating is that you are very unclear in the *prose* of the question. You say "pulling", "putting", "read", "stored", "importing", "re-pasting", and "export", and maybe some more. I can't tell if there are two steps or twenty. It feels like you're talking in circles, so I don't know how the code is corresponding to the prose. I think you might also be having some fundamental misunderstandings of what can be accomplished within an Excel file, and what must be performed by the Excel program.

Comment: Don't assume "it's not our concern". The code has to be complete (that's the C in MCVE). You should be doing ALL your code editing OUTSIDE of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you. As I am not a very skilled excel user, python script writer, or anything to do with coding, it is very difficult for me to use text to explain the issue. However, I do thank you for that and I will try to re-think the issue and possibly update this in the future. As far as addressing the not useful to other readers information, I feel I am being told separate things from different people. I am sorry, I did not want to make this difficult for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

> The intended goal is to have the math done either during export, after it is exported but before it is imported to another file, or during import.

XlsxWriter, the module shown writing the Excel file, doesn't evaluate the result of the formulas that it writes. If you calculate the result in your code you can add it when writing the formula:

```
xxtab.write(8, 3, "=H9+I9", 42)
```

This is explained in more detail in the [Working with Formulas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#formula-results) section of the XlsxWriter documentation.

None of the Python Excel file writing modules evaluate formulas. The only modules that could do that are ones that automate Excel such as [XlWings](https://www.xlwings.org).

Comment: "If you calculate the result in your code you can add it when writing the formula". This would mean I would have to go and individually calculate all of the formulas. However this also means that if any of those cells change value or the formula changes, I would need to manually go through and recalculate the data. I was trying to avoid this at all costs, so I should look into XlWings then?

Comment: That is more or less why none of the modules that write Excel files from scratch try to calculate formula results: anything beyond a simple calculation is going to require a spreadsheet engine. So, if you are looking for the result of a formula exactly as Excel calculates it you will have to use a module that automates Excel such as Xlwings, on Windows and MacOS. (On Linux there are some modules that can automate OpenOffice/Libreoffice also.)