# How to calculate a formula in Excel and pull the calculated value with OpenPyXL

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to copy/paste quantities from one excel form into another excel form (that i use as a template) that calculates COGS, and then take the sum of the COGS and assign it to a variable. After some research on OpenPyXL, it looks like you cant calculate the formula in real-time, so i am attempting to save the file with the quantities copied, then re open it, grab my COGS sum, and clear out the quantities to leave it as a blank template.

However, when i do this, i can see that it is pasting the quantity values and clearing them out, but the total COGS value remains 'None.'

This is my first attempt at a Python application after reading through most of Automate the Boring, so I am quite new to this. Any help would be appreciated!

```
# TODO: Calculate total sell using order form and total cost using ' Costing.xlsx
# Create variables to hold qty of each trim from the total_sheet
costing_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Z:\\Costing.xlsx')
costing_sheet = costing_wb['COSTING']
for i in range(3, 46, 1):
    costing_sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=4).value = total_sheet.cell(row=i, column=3).value
# Save Costing Sheet
costing_wb.save('Z:\\Costing.xlsx')

# TODO: total_COGS not grabbing value, returning as 'None'
# Reopen costing sheet and set COGS value
costing_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Z:\\Costing.xlsx', data_only=True)
costing_sheet = costing_wb['COSTING']
total_COGS = costing_sheet['I6'].value

# Empty Column D contents and save as blank
costing_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Z:\\Costing.xlsx')
costing_sheet = costing_wb['COSTING']
for i in range(5, 48, 1):
    costing_sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value = None
costing_wb.save('Z:\\Costing.xlsx')
```

Comment: If you're using `data_only=True` you will need to open and save the file with something that does evaluate formulae, such as MS Excel.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I will look into some different options.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975124/how-to-refresh-excel-using-python

Comment: Also check out this answer to another question for insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40250509/95852